# How to send SQL query only once and protect for duplicates with Worker service

Tags: c#, sql, database, service-worker

I created a service in windows *Worker service* that connects to the database at regular intervals and sends the first newest row in the table to the API

But how to make the service send the same row only once and wait until the next new one appears.

`ID` cannot have the same value, is it possible to create a condition when `dbResult[0]` (id) of the already sent row `!=` `dbResult[0]` can be sent ?

My part of code:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
     while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = "User=SYSDBA;" +
                                          "Password=masterkey;" +
                                          "Database=test.DTB;" +
                                          "DataSource=localhost;" +
                                          "Port:3050";

                FbConnection mConnection = new FbConnection(connectionString);
                mConnection.Open();

                FbTransaction mTransaction = mConnection.BeginTransaction();

                string SQLCommandText = "select first 1 * from TABLE where NAME = 449 order by DATE desc ";

                FbCommand mCommand = new FbCommand(SQLCommandText, mConnection, mTransaction);

                FbDataReader mReader = mCommand.ExecuteReader();

                if (mReader.Read())
                {
                    var values = new object[mReader.FieldCount];
                    {
                        mReader.GetValues(values);
                        var dbResult = values.Distinct().ToArray();
                        var dbResults = (string.Join("|", dbResult));

                        var result = new
                        {
                            ID = dbResult[0],
                            NAME = dbResult[1],
                            DATE = dbResult[2],
                        };

                        var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);

                    }
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Problem reading the database.");
            }

            await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE after get nice clue from *Barr J*

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
     while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = "User=SYSDBA;" +
                                          "Password=masterkey;" +
                                          "Database=test.DTB;" +
                                          "DataSource=localhost;" +
                                          "Port:3050";

                FbConnection mConnection = new FbConnection(connectionString);
                mConnection.Open();

                FbTransaction mTransaction = mConnection.BeginTransaction();

                string SQLCommandText = "select NAME, DATE from TABLE where NAME = 449 and ISSENT = 0";

                FbCommand mCommand = new FbCommand(SQLCommandText, mConnection, mTransaction);

                FbDataReader mReader = mCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (mReader.Read())
                {
                    var values = new object[mReader.FieldCount];
                    {
                        mReader.GetValues(values);
                        var dbResult = values.Distinct().ToArray();
                        var dbResults = (string.Join("|", dbResult));

                        var result = new
                        {
                            ID = dbResult[0],
                            NAME = dbResult[1],
                            DATE = dbResult[2],
                        };

                        var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);

                        using FbConnection UpdateConnection = new(connectionString);

                        UpdateConnection.Open();

                        FbCommand writeCommand = new("update TABLE set ISSENT = @isSentValue where ID= @idValue", UpdateConnection);
                        writeCommand.Parameters.Add("@isSentValue", 1);
                        writeCommand.Parameters.Add("@idValue", dbResult[0]);
                        writeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Problem reading the database.");
            }

            await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remember the latest id in a class field and add the `id`> `latestId` condition into the select.

Comment: Why not run the task when there is a new record inserted?

Comment: Is your intention to send any new rows to the API?  If you only send the first new row, there is a chance it will miss some data.  What if 5 new rows had been added at the same time?  Obviously I don't fully understand your project, but I would recommend added a field to the table that acts as a flag that you can set to true if it has been sent to the API.  Of course you can't change the flag with a SELECT statement, but you may want a simple Stored Procedure to update the flag and give you the data at the same time.

Comment: Is there any tutorial how remember latest id in a class field ? I think its a good way how achiev my goal. When latest id will be remebered no need send only first one row.

Comment: As your code runs every 10 seconds, the table may have been inserted with lot of new records, you need to sync all those rows[by calling the API], so at class level you could maintain a member `Dictionary<int,int> prevIDset` , then you could check the presence of the currently obtained IDs with prior run and only send those that are new, and clear out that prevIDset, fill them with the new IDs that are being sent in this run.

Comment: To avoid state loss if your service crashes and gets started again, this previous ID set can be persisted in a disk file instead - this is optional depends on how crucial your sync is. Also, you can maintain the db connection instead of opening and closing it every 10secs.

Comment: You might want to implement a caching, starting with MemCache or Memory caching. And when you get the data (Id or whatever identifier) cache it after reading from database. Then, when you query again from Db, look for values that is greater than that Cached_Id or != Cached_Id order by any Date field so you would always get the newer data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using a worker and running async operation, I would not recommend to mix conditions that will complicate the already cumbersome debugging process.

I would add a column to your table as bit and use it as a flag column called `IsSent`

and then your query would look like:

`select...... where name = X and IsSent = Y ...."`

this way you will get only rows that are not sent.
you can otherwise query the row in the code and check if the ID was sent.

cleaner, better, easier.

Make your code maintainable.

Comment: sounds perfect, i created column and i have one more question, how to update flag ````isSent```` ? first do ````select ...```` and after ````update ... ```` same row? i mean add for example to column ```` isSent```` variable ````Y````

Comment: Yes, if it's not sent then update

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to implement [MemCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) or simple memory caching on your worker service, by caching your new data. Either the whole or just the key identifier field value. Then, you can pass that value the next time you query the Db where the Id > CachedId or Id != CachedId order by  desc.

At any point, when you retrieve the data, you cache it/upsert your cache with that Id.

These are some examples/references for your knowledge

https://qawithexperts.com/article/c-sharp/in-memory-cache-c-explanation-with-example/302